# Access to outputs of the middle layers in the fine tuned network in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I have fine tuned vgg16 in Keras with this layers:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
vgg16 (Model)                (None, 1, 1, 512)         14714688  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              525312    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 512)               524800    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 10)                5130      
=================================================================
Total params: 15,769,930
Trainable params: 8,134,666
Non-trainable params: 7,635,264
```

But I can just extract the features of my input image from `flatten_1 , dense_1  ...  , dense_3` by `model.layers[1].output , model.layers[1].output , ... , model.layers[5].output`

So how can I extract the features in the middle layers of vgg16?

Comment: Could you provide reproducible code? My guess is that you should just access the vgg16 model in the same manner you access the intermediate layers of `model`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern to get the output of intermediate layers for a given input `x_test`:

```
import keras.backend as K

get_layer = K.function(
    [model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
    [model.layers[LAYER_DESIRED].output])
layer_output = get_layer([x_test, 0])[0]
```

where `LAYER_DESIRED` is the index of the layer you want to output.